# How to use MyBatis with CDI

Tags: cdi, mybatis

I am writing a web application and I am using MyBatis framework for persistence. I want to use CDI to inject the mappers easily and to manage the transaction declaratively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyBatis has official CDI support:

Mapper declaration:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {
  @Select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = #{userId}")
  User getUser(@Param("userId") String userId);
}
```

Mapper Usage:

```
public class MyService {

    @Inject UserMapper userMapper;

    public User doSomeStuff(String userId) {
       return this.userMapper.getUser(userId);
    }
}
```

More information in docs: http://mybatis.org/cdi/